# How do one writes a karate plugin for a different protocol?

Tags: karate

I want to write some sort of plugin for karate to:

1. being able to test non-http protocol;
2. provide some DSL to make it easier to use;
3. have that plugin as a simple maven dependency to add to a project to use it right away.

I've seen https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling, but it's not exactly what I want.

Same for https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#calling-java, it doesn't really allow defining some new DSL words to help with another protocol. Just a bunch of Java function calls in feature files.

Comment: apologies for closing this as a duplicate, but I hope all the info you need is in the linked answer. karate is designed so that extending it is via glue code (JS or Java) and NOT via adding new keywords to the DSL. yes, I know this is controversial and you can read the github-issue threads linked in the other answer to know the whole reasoning and arguments for both sides